# How many ways can n people, sitting in a circle, be re-arranged so no person moves further than one seat

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Here's a pretty tricky recursive formula I am trying to find.

As in the title, the question is:

> Assume $n$ people are seated in a circle.  In how many ways can
>   their seating be re-arranged (one person per seat!) so no person moves
>   more than one seat away from their original place (any person can move one 
>   seat to their left, right or stay in his/her seat)? Any two re-arrangements 
>   that are equivalent by rotation are counted as identical.
>
> Find a recursive formula and initial cases.

**EDIT**: A person can stay in his/her original seat.

Let's start calculating the initial cases:

$ n=1 $ then there is only one possible arrangement, so $ a_1=1$

$ n=2 $ then there are two arrangements: $<1,2>$  and $<2,1>$ but since the personals sit in a circle, those cases are actually equal, then $ a_2=1$

$ n=3 $ then the possible arrangements are:

$<1,2,3>,<1,3,2>, <2,1,3>, <2,3,1>, <3,1,2>, <3,2,1>$

And after removing the dups, we are left with:

$<1,2,3> <1,3,2>$

And so on and on.
Well, to make things "quicker" I used an algorithm I created that outputs this recursive values, so here's the list:
$a_1 = 1; dups:0$

$a_2 = 1; dups:1$

$a_3 = 2; dups:4$

$a_4 = 6; dups:3$

$a_5 = 11; dups:2$

$a_6 = 18; dups:2$

$a_7 = 29; dups:2$

$a_8 = 47; dups:2$

$a_9 = 76; dups:2$

It is easy to see that the first 4 sequences has random duplicates number, but for $a_i, i >=5 $ the duplicates are always 2.

Here I am stuck. Iv'e tried any technique I know, but I cant figure out how to bring the information Iv'e gathered into a recursive formula.

The only reasonable idea I had, is to split the recursion:

First, supply those 4 initial cases:

$ for 1<=i<=5 a_1 = 1, a_2=1, a_3 = 2, a_4 = 6, a_5 = 11 $

For $ i > 5, a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2} $

But I am not sure such definition is even legal.

Comment: What do you mean by only move one seat? Can a person only move either left or right? or can it be both? Can a person move $0$ seats, as in stand up and sit down? Are there a limit to chairs?

Comment: The meaning of "any person can only move one sit (of his left/right)" is not clear.  Possibly you have in mind an original seating (in a circle).  You then ask how many seatings differ from the original one only in accordance with the restriction that each person sits either to the left or right of their original seat.  Perhaps you mean to allow some of the people to keep their original seat (and thus the original seating would be included in the count).

Comment: @hardmath Probably a non-native English speaker at the table, eh?

Comment: @hardmath your'e absolutely right, I forgot to mention that a person can stay in his seat in the re-arrangement.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes indeed, not a native speaker but doing my best to be as clear as possible, as tough as at might be sometimes.

Comment: The people and the seats are numbered right?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel only the people are numbered

Comment: It also would appear that there is one seat per person.

Comment: I've edited the problem statement (and title) for clarity per your Comment.  Please review to check whether I unintentionally changed your meaning.

Comment: I've answered a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175359/n-objects-in-circle-with-fixed-placement-number-of-permutations-made-only-of-tr/2175416#2175416) but without the condition on rotations being equivalent. The only difference here, I believe, is that your formula for $g(n)$ will not have the $+2$ for cases of clockwise and anticlockwise rotations of everyone by $1$ chair.

Comment: If two people sitting next to each other move one space in the same direction, then the displaced person has to move in the same direction, and so must the next, and so on, until everyone in the circle has moved in that direction. Because this is a rotation, it's equivalent to doing nothing. So, you are counting the number of ways to pair off neighbours, or not pair them off, ignoring rotations.

Comment: It is known that the number of allowed permutations (setting aside the issue of rotational equivalence) is the permanent of a circulant $0,1$-matrix with three ones per row.  Computation of that permanent can be done in linear time, cf. [Computation of sparse circulant permanents via determinants](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379502003300), which in principle allows us to restate the result via a recurrence.